# How can I send this list as one message in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I just tried adding a listrole command on my discord bot which lists every user with a certain role.
However I can't seem to find a solution where my bot sends the whole list as one single message, it sends out every single member in the list as one message, which gets annoying with a large amount of members.

Here's my code so far:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def listrole(ctx, role:discord.Role):
    members = role.members
    if len(members) > 100:
        await ctx.send("Too many members to list")
    else:
        for member in members:
            memberlist = ''.join(f"{member.display_name}#{member.discriminator}")
            await ctx.send(memberlist)
```

Help is greatly appreciated, I'm very new to Python in general

Comment: Also, `str(member)` will give the members username + discriminator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `memberlist` before the loop, and append to it. Then, join all the items in that list into one long string separated by newlines, and send it *after* the loop completes:

```
memberlist = []
for member in members:
    memberlist.append(f"{member.display_name}#{member.discriminator}")
await ctx.send('\n'.join(memberlist))
```

Comment: Glad that worked. I added emphasis that it should be _after_ the loop in case anyone else sees this answer in the future.